# My road won't follow the path

Tags: path, curve-modifier

So I was creating a mountain road, and i wanted to add another surface to the base road i had already created, but after applying the Array to the road and the Curve modifier set to follow the path my road would do this instead of aligning with the path.

[image: road gone crazy]

I just want it to align on top of the road i already have

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the origin of the object is at the same position as the origin of the curve?

Comment: Could it be that you have a rotation of the object duplicated along the curve that was not applied before the Curve modifier is called ? It seems that the object is orbiting around a point that is following the road.